# RegExp help (working but need an exclusion)

Tags: regex, inclusion

I am need of some regex help.

I have a list like so:

```
/hours_3203
/hours_3204
/hours_3205
/hours_3206
/hours_3207
/hours_3208
/hours_3309
/hours_3310
/hours_3211
```

I am using this regex to find all entries that start with 32 or 33:

```
/hours_3[23]/
```

and this is working.

However I was thrown a curve ball when I was told I need to **exclude** `hours_3211` from matching in this list.

How can I adjust my regex to match on all `hours_3[23]` but NOT match on `/hours_3211`?

Alternately, when I have a list like this:

```
/hours_3412
/hours_3413
/hours_3414
/hours_3415
/hours_3516
/hours_3517
/hours_3518
/hours_3519
```

I have been using a regex of:

```
/hours_3[45]/
```

to find all `hours_34x` and `/hours_35x`

How I can adjust this:

```
/hours_3[45]/
```

to find the above but **also** find/match on `/hours_3211?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I adjust my regex to match on all `hours_3[23]` but NOT match on `hours_3211`?

Use negative lookahead `(?!)`:

```
/hours_3(?!211)[23]/
```

> How I can adjust `/hours_3[45]/` to find the above but ALSO find/match on `/hours_3211`?

Use alternation `|`:

```
/hours_3(?:[45]|211)/
```

**Edit:**

More appropriately, the above only specifies if it matches or not. If you want the actual full match returned, you want to add `.*` to the end of the RegExp like so:

```
/hours_3(?!211)[23].*/
/hours_3(?:[45]|211).*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to both parts!  Everyone else still got up votes.

these both also worked for me:

    /hours_3([45]|211)/

    /hours_3(20|3)/

Not sure how much of a difference there is between them?  (regex force is weak with this one!)  HAHA...  the more advanced regex still escapes me.

Comment: the `(?:)` is called a non-capture group. It is used to group without matching to output. I'm assuming this is JavaScript (correct me if I'm wrong), and so if you use regular grouping `()` and try to use `String.prototype.match()` for instance, then you will not only match the entire expression, but whatever is in `()` will also be outputted as the second match in the output. Using `(?:)` in this case means that only your entire match is returned.

Comment: @whispers For `/hours_3(20|3)/` this is fine assuming you wouldn't want to match something like `hours_3210`, since you specify that a `0` must follow the `2`.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I adjust my regex to match on all `hours_3[23]` but NOT match on `hours_3211`?

You can use insert a negative lookahead sub pattern:

```
/hours_3(?!211)[23]/
```

`(?!211)` is negative lookahead to disallow `211` after `hours_3` thus disallowing `hours_3211`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your adding 3211 to the second Regex which would be something like this ....

```
hours_(3[45]|3211)
```

The first one would be a negative lookahead

```
hours_3[23](?!11)
```